# Convert this format of time to seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have a column with data that looks like this

```
'1970-01-01 01:15:00.0000000' 
(01(days):15(hours):00(minutes):0000000(seconds))
```

The date is irrelevant but I want to convert the time component to seconds. I want to output for this row to be be `140400`.

Comment: Please explain where 140,400 comes from.  Why would you interpret 1:15 a.m. at 15 hours.

Comment: How is `1970-01-01 01:15:00.0000000'` 1 day 15 hours? I would expect it to be 1 hour 15 minutes, which is `4500`.

Comment: Looks like 140,400 is 1 day and 15 hours. I think the timestamp is being misused by OP, but that's a guess.

Comment: OP will need to substring his components out.

Comment: If they are misusing (abusing) the `datetime2` datatype, then I dread to think how they store 24+ days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like hour is days, minutes is hours, etc

```
Declare @d DATETIME2='1970-01-01 01:15:00.0000000'

Select (datepart(hour,@d)*3600*24)
      +(datepart(minute,@d)*3600)
      +(datepart(second,@d)*60)
```

Returns

```
140400
```

Answer (score 3):

If you really are abusing the `datetime2` datatype, and using hours to store days, minutes to store hours, seconds to store minutes, and centiseconds to store seconds... You could do this...

```
DECLARE @YourDatetime datetime2(7) = '1970-01-01 01:15:00.0100000';

SELECT (DATEPART(HOUR,@YourDatetime) * 86400) +
       (DATEPART(MINUTE,@YourDatetime) * 3600) +
       (DATEPART(SECOND,@YourDatetime) * 60) +
       (DATEPART(MILLISECOND, @YourDatetime) / 10)
```

But I **strongly** suggest you stop abusing the `datetime2` data type. Hours should be hours, not days. Hopefully that's why you're trying to do what you're asking.

This, however, assumes you don't have any values with 24 or more hours, as a value like `'1970-01-01 24:40:00.0100000'` can't be stored in any Date and Time data type.

Comment: This is how the data exists in the source system. I didn't design it.

Comment: *"I didn't design it."* That doesn't mean you shouldn't fix it, @PJ.SQL . It's simply wrong. *Very* wrong.

Comment: Yeah let me just go right into the source system that I didn't design and don't have access to and make that edit...

Comment: Then you should probably feedback to whomever did, @PJ.SQL . "I didn't design it" didn't say to me that you weren't able to fix it. There are many people who work and amend applications they didn't create; in fact it's more likely that people are working on applications that didn't design, or at least not initially.

Comment: Comments like "If you really are abusing..." come off as condescending and snarky. I would suggest when you leave feedback in the future you find more tactful ways to communicate.

Comment: The problem is it *is* abuse of the data type, @PJ.SQL , as I highlight in the answer. Misuse really doesn't convey the severity of how bad that that usage is. The reason you have the question you do is because of that usage. Have the design fixed (that doesn't need to be you) and it isn't a problem because the data type is actually representative of what you have. Like I say in the answer as well, the whole process fall over once you get the 24 days; so I hope that is never needed because things will go really wrong.

Comment: I apologise if you feel that it is condescending, however, that is not my intent; it is to highlight to problem's source and it's severity.

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable interpretation of the question returns 90,900:

```
select datediff(second, '1969-12-31', '1970-01-01 01:15:00.0000000')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datediff()` to compute the number of seconds since your reference date:

```
datediff(s, '1970-01-01', @mydatetime)
```

I suspect that you actually want to start on January 1st, 1970, because that's epoch's starting point. If you really want one day before, then:

```
datediff(s, '1969-12-31', @mydatetime)
```